# Multiple circular jquery slideshows in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am using a circle slide show from the link below.

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/779/Lightweight-Circle-slideshow

Can somebody help me get more than one slide show in a page?  thanks

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: well the first one will work, but the second one just remains, stagnant and doest move.  im am just diplicating the the html they have on the site>

Comment: They're using Ids. You will need to use classes instead, because Ids must be unique and will break if you have duplicates.

Comment: I change the rotatescroll id to class, but I get the same result, do you think i would need to dig further into the code?  I actually ahve a ton of sliders.  go to  http://torontochinesesoccer.com/simplerslideinslide/ to see what i am trying to achieve....a circle slider in each slide lol...

Comment: figured it out!!!!  used different id for different sliders, then made all the initition statements in the same function...

Answer (score 0):

figured it out!!!! used different id for different sliders, then made all the initition statements in the same function..